# is that possible to use only ipod touch to test an iphone application?

Tags: iphone

i only have a ipod touch and is it enough for me to test an app i have write for an iphone?

Comment: That depends - does your app need to make phone calls?

Comment: no, but it needs location based services..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to have both an iPhone and an iPod Touch for testing purpose. However, don't worry if you only own an iPod Touch. As long as you don't use iPhone-only functionalities (phone, SMS, etc), you're good. One bonus is that the iPod Touch is generally less powerful than an iPhone, therefore you know how well your app performs in a slow device.

As for the location-based service, iPod Touch uses WiFi to determine locations, so if you don't need GPS, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need to use something your iPod doesn't have (GPS, camera, ...) yes, it's OK

Answer (score 0):

yes and no

anything the ipod touch can do will happen on the iphone (obviously there are screen differences between the iphone 4 and an ipod touch 3 and below) but all the functions in the ipod touch will be replicated in the iphone.

however if your application needs to use anything the iphone has only then you can't check it on the ipod touch. Anything that uses the microphone, or an internet connection without wifi etc etc won't work.