# Can we use iPod touch for iPhone app Development 

Tags: iphone, macos, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is that possible to use only ipod touch to test an iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685201/is-that-possible-to-use-only-ipod-touch-to-test-an-iphone-application)

Due to financial problem ,I am unable to buy iPhone,so
I bought a new iPod touch 4g. Is it perfect for development ,connecting to xcode and running in iPod Touch Device.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to test anything relating to cellular operations, but the rest should be pretty much identical.

Comment: @MarcB would you like to make that an answer, so it can be marked correct?

Comment: Search well before you post any question.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your code has nothing to do with cellular operations, you should be go to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to test the functionalities like Phone call,Sms which are available on iPhone and unavailable on iPod you are good to go.